# Dublicate rows from join in sql

Tags: sql, join, double, row

I have two tables:
Document Header and Document Line.

From Document Header I'm using:

**- Document No

- Imported On

- Responsibility Center**

From Document Line I'm suing:
 **- No_**

Example of my code:

```
SELECT 
       DocHeader.[Document No_]             AS DocNo
      ,DocHeader.[Imported on]              AS ImportedOn
      ,DocLine.No_                          AS BoxNo
      ,DocHeader.[Responsibility Center]    AS Center
      ,CASE 
             WHEN DocHeader.[Status] = 0 THEN 'Posted'
             WHEN DocHeader.[Status] = 1 THEN 'Imported'
             WHEN DocHeader.[Status] = 2 THEN 'Processed'
             WHEN DocHeader.[Status] = 3 THEN '3'
             ELSE 'Empty'
             END AS STATUS

  FROM [MDR].[dbo].[nav_BG$IC_Document_Header]  AS DocHeader
  JOIN [MDR].[dbo].[nav_BG$IC_Document_Line]    AS DocLine      ON DocHeader.[Document No_] = DocLine.[Document No_]
  WHERE DocHeader.[Document No_] = 'BGLTD0005237'
```

The problem is that my code is creating multiple rows from the same document.

One DocNo can Have more then one BoxNo.
He is making doubled BoxNo for each DocNo.
Where I'm doing something wrong?
Example of the result:

```
DocNo ImportedOn BoxNo Center Status

1234  2019-11-20  12    B01    Posted
1234  2019-11-20  12    B01    Posted
7777  2019-11-20  12    B01    Posted
7777  2019-11-20  12    B01    Posted
```

The proper way would be:

```
DocNo ImportedOn BoxNo Center Status
1234  2019-11-20  12    B01    Posted
7777  2019-11-20  12    B01    Posted
```

**Solution was to add filter in where clause for Document Type.**

Comment: How do you want to resolve the "duplicates?"  Can you add sample data to your question which explains the problem?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I make a correction with the result and expected result.

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of the tables? Such as DocLine JOIN DocHeader?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the MAX() function? It will return the largest value of the selected column and if I have understood your question correctly, should remove you duplicated row.

```sql
MAX(DocHeader.[Document No_]) AS DocNo
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was my bad.
I notice that I must use Document type in my where clause.

Comment: Ahh, no problem.